# open a link in a new window from database table not work

Tags: php

I have a database with a table of links and I want to make a button that opens this link from the database in a new window, but it seems I do something wrong on my code.
But when i click the button nothing happens
[image: Print from page]
This is the code I use

```
<span><?php echo $data['link']; ?></span>
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='.$data['link'].';" value="View" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

As these are links why use buttons and a form rather than standard links?

You could simply have:

```
<span><?php echo $data['link']; ?></span>
<a class="faux-button" href="<?php echo $data['link']; ?>" target="_blank">View</a>
```

You can then use CSS to style the .faux-button as if it's a button if desired.
It takes Javascript out of the equation where it's really not needed...

Alternatively if it really needs to be a button:

```
<span><?php echo $data['link']; ?></span>
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $data['link']; ?>')" value="View" />
</form>
```

The issue is that you were not using PHP to output the link within your Javascript code.